# What to return from an async function in Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Inside the async function, do I need to return await for the function to complete correctly, or is the code below fine?

```
const db = admin.firestore();

export const onUserCreate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async event => {
    try {
        const user: User = {
            userId: event.data.uid,
            email: event.data.email
        };

        await db.doc(`users/${user.userId}`).set(user, {merge: true});
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

Comment: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/

Answer (score 0):

This function already returns a promise that only resolves after your `db.doc(...).set(..)` has itself resolved. `return await` would in this case be redundant.

So I think your code is fine as is, but it's simple enough that there is the possible improvement of forgetting about using async/await entirely, and just returning the promise directly. Eg: `return db.doc(...).set(...)`, without declaring the function as async.

Comment: What would happen if the catch block triggered for any reason prior to the await?

Comment: @DougStevenson In either case (function declared async or direct return), the returned promise would be rejected with an error *if* it's the `db.doc` call that threw it originally. If it wasn't that call that threw the error (like if `event` is undefined, for example), then with an async function it still rejects the promise, but with a direct return, the error would bubble up the call stack as usual.